# Python & Numba: incorrect checksum for freed object

Tags: python, numpy, memory-management, numba

I'm trying to use a loop to update an array in Numba, as I know that Numba doesn't support array creation. In a nutshell, my function looks like:

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def innerFunc(arr):
    for i in range(10000):
        arr[i] = arr[i] * 100
    return arr

def outerFunc(arr):
    arr = innerFunc(arr)
    return arr

def main():
    ####Create two numpy arrays with 10,000 random numbers each####
    ####and call them arr1 and arr2####
    outerFunc(arr1)
    outerFunc(arr2)
    return arr1, arr2
```

However, when I run `main`, I keep seeing an error like this:

> incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified
>   after being freed.
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

And this error doesn't always occur at the same place. Sometimes the error occurs after the first `outerFunc` is finished, but it could show up even before the first `outerFunc` is done.

Does it have to do with the fact that I'm doing an inplace update, calling `outerFunc` twice, or both? Am I doing something with memory management?

Comment: Numba supports array creation: http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/numpysupported.html#other-functions

Comment: @JoshAdel Does it support array creation in the ```nopython``` mode? I thought that's why we needed loop-jitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works with Numba 0.37 (and likely for a number of versions earlier):

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def innerFunc(arr):
    for i in range(10000):
        arr[i] = arr[i] * 100
    return arr

def outerFunc(arr):
    arr = innerFunc(arr)
    return arr

def main():
    arr1 = np.random.normal(size=(10000,))
    arr2 = np.random.normal(size=(10000,))
    outerFunc(arr1)
    outerFunc(arr2)
    return arr1, arr2
```

But you could also do:

```
@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def func2(x):
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        x[i] = x[i] * 100
    return x

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def func(N):
    arr1 = np.random.randn(N)
    arr2 = np.random.randn(N)

    arr1 = func2(arr1)
    arr2 = func2(arr2)

    return arr1, arr2
```

And run `func(10000)` and that will work as well.

What version of Numba are you using?

Comment: I'm using 0.37.0.

Comment: What was wrong with my code? I didn't use ```@nb```?

Comment: I'm not sure since you didn't provide a complete example of runnable code. The `nb` is just an alias and is dependent on how I chose to import numba. Depending on how you did it, it doesn't necessarily have to be the same.